# magento 2 - How to create new object Product?

Tags: magento2, product, save

How to create new object Product ?
Example:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->sku = 'fdfds';
...
$product->save();
```

Comment: in which file are u performing this change ?

Comment: I would like to apply for running file batch: app/code/myPool/Batch/Console/Command/batch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This is a quick dirty code, use dependency instead.

Here is example how to create product model object :

```
<?php 
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); manager
 $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
 $product->setSku('sku'); // Set your sku here
 $product->save();
?>
```

Another example : You can use it like create a file on root example.php and save the below code:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$_product->setName('Test Product');
$_product->setTypeId('simple');
$_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$_product->setSku('test-SKU');
$_product->save();
?>
```

Comment: Object manager must not be used directly

Comment: It is recommended to use dependency injection rather than directly using object Manager

Comment: also for products, one should always use the Factory classes instead of using the direct model classes.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old question, but the selected answer is **completly** wrong.

The answer from Manashvi Birla is kind of good but it has 2 problems

1. He says he is using factory but infact he is not
2. A product model should not save itself, the respository should do it. I think using save function on product model is even deprecated.

If you wish to use factory on product model class, you will have to do the following

```
/**
     * SaveProduct constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->product = $product->create();
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
```

```
<?php
class SaveProduct
{
    private $product;
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * SaveProduct constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function execute(): void
    {
        // example product defination
        $this->product->setSku('test-simple');
        $this->product->setName('test name simple');
        $this->product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $this->product->setSize_general(193);
        $this->product->setStatus(1);
        $this->product->setTypeId('simple');
        $this->product->setPrice(10);
        $this->product->setWebsiteIds([1]);
        $this->product->setCategoryIds([31]);

        // repository saves product
        $this->productRepository->save($this->product);
    }
}
```

Factories are well explained on this article
http://rosenborgsolutions.com/articles/magento/magento-new-class-instance

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. I was overriding the core Braintree Config related issue that is cropping up in Magento 2.4.x and wanted a clean solution. Thank you!

Comment: should be accepted answer! still working perfect in 2023

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to use dependency injection rather than directly using object Manager. Example: In your controller file you can use following code :

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_product = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


public function execute()
{
   $this->_product->setSku('test-simple');
    $this->_product->setName('test name simple');
    $this->_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $this->_product->setSize_general(193); 
    $this->_product->setStatus(1);
    $this->_product->setTypeId('simple');
    $this->_product->setPrice(10);
    $this->_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $this->_product->setCategoryIds(array(31));
    $this->_product->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
        'manage_stock' => 1, 
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, 
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, 
        'is_in_stock' => 1, 
        'qty' => 100 
        )
    ); 
    $this->_product->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi @manashvibirla, I am stuck in a similar situation. I want to create a new product on ProductSaveAfter observer in magento2. But for some reason it throws 500 internal server error. Alternative is to use DI and intercept on ProductSaveAfter event. Can you help me achieve same. Here is my question on Magento Stack. 

[Magento 2 : Error while adding product programatically On Observer Event `catalog_product_save_after`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176306/magento-2-error-while-adding-product-programatically-on-observer-event-catalo)

Comment: you should always use Factory classes, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory in your case.