# Magento 2 : Error while adding product programatically On Observer Event `catalog_product_save_after`

Tags: magento2, product, programmatically, duplicate, create-product

I am trying to add product programmatically on `catalog_product_save_after` observer.

Basically what i try to achieve is create a Duplicate Sample product of current product if `PRODUCT-SKU-sample` does not exist otherwise Update the price of `PRODUCT-SKU-sample` Sample product.

---

### Update

Can i use **`Plugin`** or **`interceptor`** instead of using Observer to create Sample Product on Save Product Event ?

---

> File : Namespace/Modulename/Observer/Catalog/ProductSaveAfter.php

```
$_product = $observer->getProduct();
$isSampleOrderEnabled = $observer->getProduct()->getData('enable_sample_order');

if($isSampleOrderEnabled == 1){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
    $_mediapath = BP.'/pub/media/'. 'catalog/product' . $_product->getImage();
    $imageUrl  =  $store->getBaseDir(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product' . $_product->getImage();

    $getProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $sampleSkuExists = $getProduct->getIdBySku($_product->getSku().'-sample');

    $sampleProductPrice = $observer->getProduct()->getData('sample_price');
    if($sampleSkuExists == FALSE) {

        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        try {
            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
                    ->setAttributeSetId($_product->getAttributeSetId()) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                    ->setTypeId('simple') 
                    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) 
                    ->setSku($_product->getSku().'-sample') //SKU
                    ->setName($_product->getName()."-sample")
                    ->setWeight(4.0000)
                    ->setStatus(1) 
                    ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
                    ->setVisibility(1) 
                    ->setPrice($sampleProductPrice) 
                    ->setMetaTitle($_product->getMetaTitle())
                    ->setMetaKeyword($_product->getMetaKeyword())
                    ->setMetaDescription($_product->getMetaDescription())
                    ->setDescription($_product->getDescription())
                    ->setShortDescription($_product->getShortDescription())
                    ->setStockData(
                        array(
                           'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                           'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                           'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                           'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                           'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                           'qty' => 99999//qty
                        )
                    );

            echo "BEFORE SAVING THE NEW PRODUCT";
            $res = $product->save();
            echo "AFTER SAVING THE NEW PRODUCT";

            var_dump($res); 
            echo $product->getEntityId();
            // Save the new Sample Product ID to original product Attribute. 
        } catch (Exception $e ) {
            echo    $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        echo "UPDATE CODE GOES HERE";
    }
}
```

I cant get past `$product->save();`. Code execution stop right there without any notice/error.

Checked all the log files. there is no relevent information there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding conditional logic.
Set the Session variable for session while executing Observer.

```
$_SESSION['NameSpace']['ModuleName'] = 'Y';
```

And then checked the very first thing in function if session variable exist. And return if value is set

```
if(isset($_SESSION['NameSpace']['ModuleName']) && $_SESSION['ModuleName']['ModuleName'] == 'Y' ){
    unset($_SESSION['NameSpace']);
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***It is logical an issue in your code.***

you have   another `save()[ $res = $product->save();]` function inside call `catalog_product_save_after` observer.

***it make recursive call of your observer***. because of `save()` call `catalog_product_save_after` which fire again your observer.

That make recursive  call of your observer.

So, you should avoid it by some logic

Comment: Well it looks like this is the issue. 
Can you please help me use Plugin or Interceptor (DI) after product save event.